# TypeError: firebaseAdmin.appCheck is not a function in `firebase-admin` appCheck

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin, firebase-app-check

I am try to implement firebase appCheck as mention in the official documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend in the node back-end side.

version: "firebase-admin": "^9.3.0",
node:  v16.13.0

But i got a type error `firebaseAdmin.appCheck is not a function` with the example code given in the official documentation.

I tried with `initializeApp` with credentials, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Admin `"9.3.0"` is very old version (released ~2 years ago, before App Check was GA). Try updating Firebase Admin to latest version:

```
npm i firebase-admin@latest
```

Comment: Thanks. I've checked their release notes and repository. Seemed support for App Check was added since version `^9.8.0`